# AngularJS using a custom filter in the html tag of a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

I have a directive with a template that looks like:

```
<span> {{foo.bar}} {{foo.car}} {{foo.dar}}</span>
```

which is called in multiple locations. The way it is called is:

```
<foo-dir foo="fooData"></foo-dir>
```

**Is there any way to apply a custom filter in the html directive tag and not in the directive itself?**

I'm hoping something exists such as:

```
ng-innertext-filter="filterName:params"
```

but it may be wishful thinking.

If that is not possible, is there a way to use the filter in the directive controller without having to apply it everywhere the directive is used?

Thanks.

**Edit:** filter code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
function someFilter() {
    return (input, filterParam) => {
        if (input && filterParam && input.length)
            if(filterParam)
                return input.filterLogic();
        return input;
    }
}
```

The filter works fine when in a templated string `{{somedata | someFilter}}`. But I am looking for a way to apply the filter to the directive tag itself.

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. Can you provide a working example of your current filter and show what result you would expect?

Comment: Ya I am trying to find a way to use the filter on the resulting string from a directive in the html tag. The current filter is:
```
import angular from 'angular';

function SomeFilter() {
    return (input, filterParam) => {
        if (input && filterParam && input.length) {
            if(filterParam) {
                return input.filterLogic();
            }
        }
        return input;;
    }
}

export default angular.module('filters.someFilter', [])
    .filter('someFilter', SomeFilter)
    .name;
```

Comment: The filter works when in templating ```{{stringData | someFilter:param}}``` but I would like to be able to apply the filter to the string that is a result of the directive instead of including it in the directive itself, so it can only be used in certain areas

Comment: Please update your question with this code. Not really readable in comments ;)

Comment: Edited the original post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you want:

> **use the filter on the resulting string from a directive in the html tag**

you need to create a template string and recompile your DOM.

This is a quite advanced use of AngularJS. I hope you enjoy it :-)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {
        bar: "1",
        car: "2",
        dar: "3"
    };
});

app.directive('foodir', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            foo: '=',   // Bind the variable to the directive's scope
            filter: '@' // Just get the string for compilation
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // This is the string on which you may want to apply a filter
            var string_template = '" bar:" + foo.bar + " car:" + foo.car + " dar:" + foo.dar';
            // Full string to compile without filter
            var html = '<span>{{' + string_template + '}}</span>';
            if ($scope.filter !== undefined)
                // Full string to compile with filter (optional)
                html = '<span>{{' + string_template + ' | '+$scope.filter+'}}</span>';
            console.log(html);
            var e = $compile(html)($scope); // Convert your string to a DOM element
            $element.replaceWith(e); // Make it the content of the directive
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <foodir foo="foo"></foodir>
  <hr/>
  <foodir foo="foo" filter="uppercase"></foodir>
  <hr/>
  <foodir foo="foo" filter="limitTo:10"></foodir>
</body>
```

Now, if you just want to apply a filter to some parts of your template (and not the full string), you can avoid the `string_template` and use basic interpolation like this:

```
var html = '<span> {{foo.bar}} {{foo.car}} {{foo.dar |' + $scope.filter + '}}</span>'
```

Comment: Using `$compile` is indeed advanced AngularJS. Also, I think unnecessary. This seems like the functional equivalent of just injecting `$filter` and using it to apply the custom filter to the output before attaching it to scope.

Comment: That's what I initially thought too. But looking deeper into it, I found no way of applying a filter globally to the innerHTML. If you have a solution, I'll be happy to read it. Not mentioning applying a filter and its parameters provided through element's attributes.

Comment: I think it might be possible, though of limited practical value, to have a higher priority standalone directive that sort of short-circuits compilation, performs its own compilation and then applies a specified filter to the output. If a custom directive is being built anyway, it'd be much more practical to just build it to apply the filter in a more conventional way.

Comment: Sounds good. I agree should indeed split this directive in 2, `foodir` type E and `filterdir` type A. I'll try go come out with something like you suggest. I think next year because I'll have little time till then and this question has a working answer atm :-D Thanks @JCFord for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the first part of your question means. If you're wanting to apply this filter to the compiled result of a directive, I'm not sure you can.  I can help with using a filter in a controller, though.

If you define a custom AngularJS filter like so:

```
app.filter('makeItPretty', function() {

    return function(value) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
    };

});
```

Then you can access your filter from within a controller by injecting the built-in `$filter` service:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($filter) {
    var makeItPretty = $filter('makeItPretty');
    var myPrettyText = makeItPretty('tHiS iS UgLy!');
});
```

Comment: I followed a bit more this lead but I ended up with something quite complex and a filter only applied to some parts of the directive, not the whole thing. I think the solution requires recompilation.